# Does it help to provide training samples with no target objects in object detection?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am training a Yolo for object detection. I was wondering if it will help to provide images with no instances of the target object present. If so, what would the VOC label of such an instance look like? just an xml file with no `<object>` tags?

Thinking about it, it doesn't seem like it will help much, given that Yolo fits anchor boxes and tries to detect objects that are not the target anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From the [darknet repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet)

> desirable that your training dataset include images with non-labeled objects that you do not want to detect - negative samples without bounded box (empty .txt files) - use as many images of negative samples as there are images with objects